# How can I convert anonymous commenters into registered users?

Tags: comments, user-registration, comment-form

I want to convert all anonymous comments that have already been posted into a registered user using the username and a randomly generated password.

I really don't know where to begin with this.

I also want to convert new anonymous commenters into a registered user. If I add a hook into **functions.php** using `register_new_user` will it automatically generate a random password for the user and email them, or do I need to make a password field under the comment form as well?

Here is my comment form when a user is not registered:

[image]

Here is what my code for the comment form looks like:

```
args = array(

    'comment_field' =>  '<div class="form-group the-comment-form"><label for="comment" class="custom-avatar">' . $useravatar_custom .

      '</label><div id="' . $textareaId . '"><textarea id="comment" class="form-control" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true" placeholder="Join the discussion..."></textarea></div></div>',      

    'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(

      'author' =>

        '<div class="form-group comments-name">' .

        '<label for="author">' . __( 'Username', 'usertheme' ) . '</label> ' .

        ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .

        '<input id="author" name="author" class="form-control" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .

        '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',


      'email' =>

        '<div class="form-group comments-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'usertheme' ) . '</label> ' .

        ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .

        '<input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .

        '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>'
```

As you see, there is a name and email required. What I want to do is make it register a new user. But I also want to generate a random password for the user.

Do I need to add a password field to the comment form? Or do I need to use the wordpress create password function? Or if I use `register_new_user` will it automatically generate a random password and email the user their new login details?

Comment: Noting that this is a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255850/how-do-i-convert-users-who-put-an-email-and-username-for-a-comment-into-register which I've closed in favor of this as it has more information. Don't repost the same question if you don't like the answers, _edit_ the question instead

Answer (score 1):

The [register_new_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_new_user/) triggers after the user has been created when the `register_new_user()` function runs and it will give you the `$id` of the new user that has been created.

If you are using [register_new_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_new_user/) you dont need a password field, wordpress will create one a send it using the email provided to the user.

So yes, using the function will create the user and generate a password, and this logins details will be send to the user.

Comment: I realized this only answered only part of my question, I upvoted but can't accept because it's not a complete answer.